# Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew, failed-installation, npx

This error occurred when trying to run `npx react-native run-android`
[error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeHZG.png)

Comment: Did you follow the steps outlined in the link?

Comment: @ivanmoskalev i've resolved the issue, thanks for the reply

Comment: @AMALMOHANN how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured a way to resolve this issue. To resolve this please follow the following steps. Here we'll be trying two steps, if you're lucky the issue will resolve in first step it self.

1. go to the project folder
2. open cmd in that folder (if you're using vscode use cntrl + ~ to open terminal)
3. `cd android` (you can also go directly to project/android folder and open cmd there)
4. now run `gradlew clean` (for modern versions: `./gradlew clean`)
5. if you get permission errors then try `chmod +x gradlew`

If your issue is resolved have a good coding else continue. Most common error is
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper`

for resolving this please following the below steps,

1. Please download JDK version 14 or above
   JDK Download link: `https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html`
2. go to `your_project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. change to gradle version 6.3 or above `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`
4. now run `npx react-native run-android`

this worked for me.